# Interface return runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

I have create some code with Go and try to implement an interface.

There is an interface

```
type CityInterface interface {
    GetAll() (models.CityResponses, error)
}
```

Then refer to this function on separated file with the same package of interface file

```
//GetAll is a function to get all city
func GetAll() (models.CityResponses, error) {
    ....

    return cities, err
}
```

Then I used that interface to service file with package services

```
func GetAllCity() (models.CityResponses, error) {
    var cityInterface repositories.CityInterface
    cities, err := cityInterface.GetAll()

    return cities, err
}
```

Why this script return panic runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference?

and it's refer to this line

```
cities, err := cityInterface.GetAll()
```

Please help me to find out this problem. Thank You.

Comment: You are calling GetAll on nil. Do you expect `cityInterface` to be anything other than nil? If so, why?

Comment: It's simply "Go", not "Go Lang" or "GoLang". Just like it's not "PythonLang" or "JavaLang"

Comment: searching "Go" only on Google search is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var cityInterface repositories.CityInterface
```

This line declares a variable of type `repositories.CityInterface` and assigns the zero value. The zero value for all interface types is nil.

Calling methods on a nil interface causes the panic you observe (what else could the runtime do if there's no concrete type stored in the interface value?).

It looks like you're trying to implement the interface with the package level function `GetAll`. That's not how it works. Interfaces are implemented by *types*, not *packages*.

To implement the `CityInterface` define a type with a `GetAll` *method*, not just a *function* named `GetAll`, and initialize the interface with a value of this type.

```
type T struct {}

func (T) GetAll() (models.CityResponses, error) {
    // Body of original GetAll function goes here.
}

func GetAllCity() (models.CityResponses, error) {
    var cityInterface repositories.CityInterface = T{} // initialize interface value
    cities, err := cityInterface.GetAll()

    return cities, err
}
```

Alternatively, get rid of the interface and `GetAllCity`; it's just a convoluted way of calling the original `GetAll` function directly.

Comment: Thanks I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 problems:

1. The implementation of the interface method should be a member function.
2. The variable `cityInterface` is not initialized to anything useful.