# why my localhost don't send any data when using database interface for mocking in Golang unit test?

Tags: database, unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm new in golang. I want to write unit tests for my functions that save data in mongodb, that are a little complicated.
There are many nested functions. e.g. A calls B, inside B, C and D is called, finally D calls E function that has a database query like `Find`.
I followed the instructions of [RESTful API in Golang using Echo - MongoDB Unit Testing in Golang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KC4Q2S2PACQ) in youtube.

So I decided to start from a little function like E.
Here is the little function that I tried to mock database relation for it:

```
func LoadUserRoles(username interface{}) ([]UserRoles, error) {

    q := bson.M{"username": username}
    ps := new([]UserRoles)
    if err := userRoleDB.Find(q).All(ps); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    return *ps, nil
}
```

I created an interface that implements exactly the Find method of mgo driver. the interface is like:

```
type CollectionAPI interface {
    Find(query interface{}) *mgo.Query
}
```

Then I created an instance of this interface and took instead of userRoleDB:

```
var userRoleMockDB      dbinterface.CollectionAPI
```

So my LoadUserRoles function changed to:

```
func LoadUserRoles(username interface{}) ([]UserRoles, error) {
    q := bson.M{"username": username}

    ps := new([]UserRoles)

    if err := userRoleMockDB.Find(q).All(ps); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return *ps, nil
}
```

The result is error in connecting to db.

**Exact error:**

**localhost didn’t send any data.**

**ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

Comment: Also I have to add, I got "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference", I think it's because of using interface according to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021012/interface-return-runtime-error-invalid-memory-address-or-nil-pointer-dereferenc)

Comment: You only declared `userRoleMockDB` as interface type `dbinterface.CollectionAPI` , but you did not show how you initialized/assigned a concrete type to the var `userRoleMockDB`. If you don't put a concrete value in var `userRoleMockDB` will you get the error that you mentioned about "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"